# how to stack groups of columns into a new matrix in r?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a 3d array in R, say the dimension is 500*3*5, call it data. So there are 5 slices of matrices, each has 500 rows and 3 columns. Now I want to create a new matrix that stacks the 5 slices vertically. So the output has 500*5 rows and 5 columns and it looks like this:

```
[dim1]   [ dim3 ]       [1]       [2]        [3]       

 1          1           data     data        data
 1          2           data     data        data
 1          3           data     data        data
 1          4           data     data        data
 1          5           data     data        data
 2
 2
 2
 ..
 500          1           data     data        data
 500          2           data     data        data
 500          3           data     data        data
 500          4           data     data        data
 500          5           data     data        data
```

So for each 500 rows, repeat the 2nd and 3rd dimension of the original array, such that column1 repeats the original row index, column2 repeats the old z dimensional index and column 3-5 are the 3 columns of data (numeric and have missing values). i just used the number 5 here, in my data the number is much bigger, so i need to be able to do this more generally. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `a` be your 3d array, you can do:

```
n <- dim(a)
b <- aperm(a, c(3,1,2))
dim(b) <- c(n[3] * n[1], n[2])
```

If you want to add the dim indices to the left, you can do:

```
b <- cbind(rev(expand.grid(dim3 = 1:n[3], dim1 = 1:n[1])), b)
```